# Why can I choose a nonsense description when offering a bounty?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bounty-remarks

There are currently no answers to [How to make \reversepath useful for drawing the following closed curve?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151010/19356), but I can offer a bounty with the description:

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

If there is no answer available, I should not be able to select this description. What do you think?

Comment: This looks like yet another layer of complication for no discernible benefit. So what if people can choose the "wrong" bounty reason?

Comment: [status-who-cares]

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow: According to Joel Spolsky's GUI Design Principle, all options must be enabled but the system will warn us when the selection does not make sense or out of the context. Thereby the users learn how the system works from their mistakes. Don't let him see this bug. :-)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think he would care if he'd see this "bug". There are so many pressing other tasks, many of which can be seen here on Meta....

Comment: Clearly you can choose that because you are batman. Or perhaps you can see the future. To be honest though, those are just defaults to choose from if you are inclined and don't want to always type the same thing. Really, if you wanted to make a silly message, choose other, and use the message BATMAN SIGNAL BROKEN! MUST FIX! REVERSE POSSIBLE??

Comment: Also, I think you are the record holder for bounties offered! 41,200 reputation awarded in bounties? You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: @TravisJ: Just for fun... :-)

Comment: Update: Now the question has already had an answer from me. But it still does not make sense to offer a bounty to my own answer. Right?